# vCard Import/Export?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, vcf-vcard

I have an Adobe Air application and I am trying to build a method of importing and exporting vCards. I was wondering if there is a simple way or does anyone know anything that could direct me.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [AS3CoreLib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/fileformats/vcard)'s implementation of it.  Fairly easy to use, just need to add the SWC to your project.